# Implement session using bottle framework

Tags: session, bottle

I'm trying to implement a session using set_cookie and get_cookie.

```
@route("/login", method=["POST","GET"])
def login():
     
    if(request.method=="POST"):
            username = request.forms["username"]
            response.set_cookie(username,username)
    ....
```

Now I have a page for an authenticated user, but how do I know if the name of the current user? Since the username is the key.

```
@route("/secrete", method=["POST","GET"])
def secrete():
     
    value = request.get_cookie(?) #how do I know the username here?
```

I tried using the same key, such that  `response.set_cookie("key", username)` but this does not allow many users login at the same time.

Comment: Sessions usually work with a database of some sort. The cookie is just a key into the database's sessions table to pull out all of the session data corresponding to a cookie presented with a request. There's nothing bottle-specific here, so any session info should apply.